# Update ListView Row on data change

Tags: java, android, listview

Can someone help me update a `ProgressBar` in a `ListView` using a callback/listener?

- Point me in the right direction?
- Tell me what I am trying to do is called?

I don't know enough about what I am trying to do to Google a tutorial. I've looked at plenty of "Download Tutorials with ProgressBar" but they don't fit what I am working on. I'm frustrated because being able to update a simple `ProgressBar` in a `ListView` would be simple, if the List view and the Async task where in the same class. But in my implementation, the `ListView` is merely an observer of the data and it should watch? be notified? Set a timer and just constantly refresh the `ListView` via `notifiyDataSetChanged()`?

My data is updated in a different class. My `ListView` Activity only looks at that data and should display the progress.

The `ListView` works great at showing the *CURRRENT* state of the data when the Activity is loaded. But fails to continue to update the `ProgressBar`s.

The data class works great at updating my object's progress property.

Now I just need to make each row update when the data has changed.

How do I get each `ListView` row to be notified when the data it is displaying has changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider using a `LocalBroadcastReceiver` in your case. When the state of the data is updated from another class, you might consider sending a broadcast event to the `Activity` which is holding the `ListView` and update the `ListView` when the broadcast is received.

To implement a broadcast receiver in your `Activity` or `Fragment` which is holding the `ListView` you need to do something like this.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  ...

  // Register to receive messages.
  // We are registering an observer (mMessageReceiver) to receive Intents
  // with actions named "custom-event-name".
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
      new IntentFilter("custom-event-name"));
}

// Our handler for received Intents. This will be called whenever an Intent
// with an action named "custom-event-name" is broadcasted.
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Get extra data included in the Intent
    String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
    // Do something with message
    yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  // notify the adapter here
  }
};

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
  // Unregister since the activity is about to be closed.
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
  super.onDestroy();
}
```

The `onReceive` function will get the callback of the broadcast sent and will update the `ListView` with the current status passed to it. I'm just sending a message in the example. You might consider passing any custom data.

Now to send the state of the data showed in the `ListView` from another class, you need to send the broadcast to the receiver registered in your `Activity` or `Fragment`.

```
// Send an Intent with an action named "custom-event-name". The Intent sent should 
// be received by the ReceiverActivity.
private void sendMessage() {
  Log.d("sender", "Broadcasting message");
  Intent intent = new Intent("custom-event-name");
  // You can also include some extra data.
  intent.putExtra("message", "This is my message!");
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

Call the `sendMessage` function on any update of your data to update the `ListView` accordingly.

Comment: well elaborated

Comment: @ReazMurshed this sends a broadcast message on every progress update. You can see in the log file just hundreds of messages being sent. Even after the upload is complete, the system tries to catch up. Do you see that as being a problem?

Comment: In case of upload you might consider sending broadcast after each segment of data uploaded. For example, you might consider publishing the progress for each 5% of the total file upload.